# Argument Identity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

When does $Arg(\bar{z})=Arg(1/z)$? To me it seems to hold for any nonzero $z$, since $1/z=\bar{z}/|z|^2$ and $Arg$ is unaffected by scalar multiplication by real numbers

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, but there are a couple notes I'd like to add:

1) If $z=0$, neither quantity is properly defined.

2) $\arg(z)$ is not affected by **positive** scalar multiplication. The fact that $|z|^2>0$ for $z\neq 0$ is important as, for example $\arg(i)=\frac{\pi}{2}\neq-\frac{\pi}{2}=\arg(-i)$ (the $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ may be replaced with $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ depending on how you define $\arg$).

Comment: How do you formally prove the equation holds then, without using "Arg isn't unaffected by positive scalar multiplication" Using just the definition of $arg(z)=\{\theta: z=|z|e^{i\theta}\}$ with the principle Arg restricted to $[-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: @user596042 You prove "$\arg$ isn't unaffected by positive scalar multiplication" by invoking that definition. If you can write $x=|x|e^{i\theta}$, you can write $cx=c|x|e^{i\theta}$, and if $c$ is positive we have $|cx|=c|x|$.